# Why display-flex not working in safari. Is there is any way to solve this problem?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

when ever I am trying to use bootstrap column in safari column grids are not working it breaks down.Is there is any way to support display-flex in the safari browser......?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 pl-0">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 pl-0">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 pl-0">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I opened this question in safari and it seems to work for your snippet :)

Comment: but I am not using safari in mac I am using safari in windows

Comment: Which Safari version are you using? Display flex should be available on the latest version https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_display_flex

Answer (score 0):

Safari supports `display: flex` since version 6.1 according to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_display_flex). The latest Safari version for Windows has been 5.1.7 from 2012, though, so `display: flex` isn't supported on Windows and there's no way to come around this problem.

*May I add that using a 8 year old browser is a really bad idea?*